# How can I make KIE workbench pull from an SVN repository?

Tags: jboss, jbpm, wildfly-8, kie, kie-workbench

I'd like to clone a new repository in the KIE workbench using SVN instead of Git. Can that be done easily or do I have to dig into the jbpm-console source code in order to add this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only clone git repositories, however you should be able to expose a SVN repository as a git repo by wrapping it.

Answer (score 1):

The other much more complicated alternative should be providing another implementation for the virtual file system provided by the uberfire project to support SVN.